# Menu "ul" overlaps submenu "ul" element on jQuery.animate() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I want my submenu to have slide down effect using

```
$.animate({top:$("#menu").outerHeight()})
```

I want my submenu to have an effect as a car(submenu) leaving the garage(first level menu) on slide down, then car parking to the garage on a slide up. I do not want to have a `$.slideDown() or $.slideUp()` effects, because I do not like the effect of increasing height.

The problem is that I can not seem to make my first-level menu overlap my submenu on sliding down or sliding up. On hover submenu just overlaps the main menu and then stays "overlapped" on slide up.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<ul id="menu_Navigation2">
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second
      <ul>
          <li>Default</li>
          <li>Default</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Third</li>
  <li>Forth
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Forth default</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">forth default</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#menu_Navigation {
    border:1px solid green;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    list-style-type:none;

}
#menu_Navigation li {
    padding:4px 4px;
}
#menu_Navigation>li {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    list-style-type:none;
    z-index:90;

    border:1px solid black;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #b5c7e4, #94b1dc);
    color:white;
    font-size:13px;
    cursor:default;
    margin-right:-4px;
    min-width:100px;
}
#menu_Navigation a {
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#menu_Navigation ul {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    padding:0px;
    min-width:106px;
    margin-left:-4.5px;
    list-style:none;
    top:-27px;
    z-index:-999;
}
#menu_Navigation ul li {
    display:block;
    border:1px solid black;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #b5c7e4, #94b1dc);
}
#menu_Navigation ul li:hover {
    border:1px solid black;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #b5c7e4, #94b1dc);
    color:blue;
}
```

To clarify, please have a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/058rqab5/34/), which illustrates the problem.

How can I achive this animate effect, so submenu appears as a whole(gradually) from the main menu then slides up to menu properly(not overlapping it)? 
Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: I've tried to modify you js code... But honestly i don't undertood what's the problem

http://jsfiddle.net/058rqab5/26/

Tecnically you have to re-write your html making the submenu as an extension of first level menu (sorry for my awful english, i'm practicing)

Comment: It is OK, your english is good:) How can I make my submenu as an extension of first level menu? I suppose it is already written as an extension. I may be wrong though.

Comment: I mean, start from a structire like mine (like prev. example) and implement a jquery to slide in/out the submenu..

Your submenu start on top because it has an absolute position. You have to calculate the height of main-menu and move "top" the submenu of that val...

Comment: do you want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/058rqab5/28/)?

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi What have you chagned there?

Comment: @MaurizioBattaghini Yes absolute position there is on purpose, because I want to have a sliding down effect of jQuery.animate({top:25px}) function. I know that I can easily hide submenu, then on hover slide it down either by setting display:block, or using $.slideDown() functions. BUT this is not what I want.

Comment: Changed a bit of CSS. Should I post it as answer because it would be difficult to explain in comment?

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi No, sorry, your edit absolutely not solving my problem.

Comment: I'm sorry I just did for your explanation.

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi it is ok, no need to apology. Probably I did not explain my problem approprietly. I have edited my post and created new fiddle, which illustrates better where actually my problem lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the z-index from:

```
#menu_Navigation>li
```

And add it to:

```
#menu_Navigation
```

For this to work(parent above children) the parent(first level of li) needs to be wrapped(the main ul) with an element with positive z-index and the children(internal ul) needs to have negative z-index(you have that).

**EDIT:** As suggested by [Shukhrat Raimov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1893261/shukhrat-raimov) I am adding his [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/058rqab5/36/) with the working code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. http://jsfiddle.net/058rqab5/35/, I added position:relative to main menu, so I can use z-index on it. Still submenu overlaps main menu. z-index here changed only li text of first-level menu to overlap text of submenu.

Comment: In the fiddle you havent removed the z-index from the LI element:#menu_Navigation2 li

Comment: Thanks for the tips. It helped. Please edit your answer and add http://jsfiddle.net/058rqab5/36/ this link, so maybe it will help someone later.